# ImportError: DLL load failed while importing module

Tags: python, python-3.x, theano

I'm trying to run the code I downloaded from this site: http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/lstm.html
and when I try to run it, it says

```
model options {'dim_proj': 128, 'patience': 10, 'max_epochs': 100, 'dispFreq': 10, 'decay_c': 0.0, 'lrate': 0.0001, 'n_words': 10000, 'optimizer': <function adadelta at 0x2043DC40>, 'encoder': 'lstm', 'saveto': 'lstm_model.npz', 'validFreq': 370, 'saveFreq': 1110, 'maxlen': 100, 'batch_size': 16, 'valid_batch_size': 64, 'dataset': 'imdb', 'noise_std': 0.0, 'use_dropout': True, 'reload_model': None, 'test_size': 500}
Loading data
Building model
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\KaguyaHour\Desktop\PythonBin\lstm.py", line 661, in <module>
    train_lstm(
  File "C:\Users\KaguyaHour\Desktop\PythonBin\lstm.py", line 517, in train_lstm
    y, f_pred_prob, f_pred, cost) = build_model(tparams, model_options)
  File "C:\Users\KaguyaHour\Desktop\PythonBin\lstm.py", line 395, in build_model
    proj = dropout_layer(proj, use_noise, trng)
  File "C:\Users\KaguyaHour\Desktop\PythonBin\lstm.py", line 84, in dropout_layer
    trng.binomial(state_before.shape,
  File "C:\Python3\lib\site-packages\theano\sandbox\rng_mrg.py", line 901, in binomial
    x = self.uniform(size=size, nstreams=nstreams, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python3\lib\site-packages\theano\sandbox\rng_mrg.py", line 872, in uniform
    rstates = self.get_substream_rstates(nstreams, dtype)
  File "C:\Python3\lib\site-packages\theano\configparser.py", line 117, in res
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python3\lib\site-packages\theano\sandbox\rng_mrg.py", line 779, in get_substream_rstates
    multMatVect(rval[0], A1p72, M1, A2p72, M2)
  File "C:\Python3\lib\site-packages\theano\sandbox\rng_mrg.py", line 61, in multMatVect
    multMatVect.dot_modulo = function(
  File "C:\Python3\lib\site-packages\theano\compile\function.py", line 306, in function
    fn = pfunc(params=inputs,
  File "C:\Python3\lib\site-packages\theano\compile\pfunc.py", line 483, in pfunc
    return orig_function(inputs, cloned_outputs, mode,
  File "C:\Python3\lib\site-packages\theano\compile\function_module.py", line 1841, in orig_function
    fn = m.create(defaults)
  File "C:\Python3\lib\site-packages\theano\compile\function_module.py", line 1714, in create
    _fn, _i, _o = self.linker.make_thunk(
  File "C:\Python3\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\link.py", line 697, in make_thunk
    return self.make_all(input_storage=input_storage,
  File "C:\Python3\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\vm.py", line 1087, in make_all
    thunks.append(node.op.make_thunk(node,
  File "C:\Python3\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\op.py", line 954, in make_thunk
    return self.make_c_thunk(node, storage_map, compute_map,
  File "C:\Python3\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\op.py", line 857, in make_c_thunk
    outputs = cl.make_thunk(input_storage=node_input_storage,
  File "C:\Python3\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\cc.py", line 1215, in make_thunk
    cthunk, module, in_storage, out_storage, error_storage = self.__compile__(
  File "C:\Python3\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\cc.py", line 1153, in __compile__
    thunk, module = self.cthunk_factory(error_storage,
  File "C:\Python3\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\cc.py", line 1623, in cthunk_factory
    module = get_module_cache().module_from_key(
  File "C:\Python3\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\cmodule.py", line 1189, in module_from_key
    module = lnk.compile_cmodule(location)
  File "C:\Python3\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\cc.py", line 1520, in compile_cmodule
    module = c_compiler.compile_str(
  File "C:\Python3\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\cmodule.py", line 2420, in compile_str
    return dlimport(lib_filename)
  File "C:\Python3\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\cmodule.py", line 317, in dlimport
    rval = __import__(module_name, {}, {}, [module_name])
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing m75022cac696dc858984a7c4467166cc6915405b19d04c2580f5acf71c834d9de: The specified module could not be found.[Finished in 9.9s]
```

So this "m75022cac696dc858984a7c4467166cc6915405b19d04c2580f5acf71c834d9de" makes me wonder what type of dll is that... Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is unanswered until now, I was having a similar problem running training with Theano on Jupyter Notebook on Win10, as I was installing packages with **pip**.

The solution for me was installing Theano with `conda install theano`, that installed all kinds of additional packages which made Theano work in the end. I used the same Jupyter Notebook on Ubuntu Google Cloud VM, and I didnt have to solve this problem.